# Вместо откладки(Debug) находится кнопка "Присоединение" в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: Сама кнопка]

[image: Папка с проектом]

В интернете был варик с удалением папка .vs в проекте, но здесь его нет.
Мне просто нужно запустить компилятор для запуска кода на C# без присоединения к Unity или к чему-то подобному. Что мне сделать, чтобы запустить откладку?

Comment: Я надеюсь вы не открываете файл `.cs`..?

Comment: нет, ConsoleApp

Comment: А может все такие открываете, откройте файл решения **.sln** тогда все запустится

Comment: только что проверил, та жа картина

Comment: Завтра у препода тогда спроошу, если получится напишу

Answer (score 0):

Вобщем такая тема:
Нужно было при создании проекта выбрать не "Консольное приложение", а "Консольное приложение .NET Framework". Просто нам препод говорил, чтобы мы создавали "Консольное приложение"
Я делал по этому видео: https://youtu.be/w8rRhAup4kg?si=OX5os4t8mPpPNjzE

Comment: Весьма странное решение. Если вам студия позволяет создать оба типа проекта, то оба типа и должны без проблем запускаться. Значит вы делаете что-то не то, ну а что именно - мы не сможем вам сказать, ибо это ваш персональный косяк.

Comment: Очень странно, скорее всего вы что-то открывали не так. Ибо ConsoleApp и ConsoleApp (.NET Framework) отличаются только тем что в первом используется .NET а во втором .NET Framework.

Comment: Это неверное решение. Беру стандартную установку Visual Studio 2022, создаю Консольное приложение (.NET 8), запускаю кнопкой без проблем.